# SDN 4, delete cache when I delete related entity

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j, spring-data-neo4j-4

There.
I'm using sdn4 with java 8.

I make this relation

```
Owner -Has- truck.
```

and delete truck using truckReposity(extends GraphRepository).
If checking truck is deleted in Neo4j broswer, It is deleted.

but Running web application has still have truck.

```
owner.removeTruck(truck);
ownerRepository.save(owner);
truckRepositry.delete(truck);
```

I'm using these codes.
Can I delete truck with relation other way?

Comment: If you removeTruck(truck) correctly removes references from both owner and truck, then using repository.delete should not require the cache to be cleared. If it does, please open an issue at https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAGRAPH with a test case/sample code, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For deleting the SDN cache you can use 
`neo4jTemplate.clear();` or `session.clear()`

Apart form that, I think it is because of the “Smart Object Mapping” that owner still has a relationship to truck.  If you query for owner again, after you have deleted truck from neo4j it should be gone.

Comment: session.clear should only be required when an entity or relation is deleted via a custom query. As long as object references are removed, using repository or session delete should work as expected